# In Scala Timestamp of now plus 5 minutes

Tags: scala, date, timestamp

In Scala, how would I make a Timestamp of a time that is 5 minutes in the future? I'm using a java.util.Date class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) (a Joda Time wrapper for scala) you can do

```
val in5mins = DateTime.now + 5.minutes
val javaDate = in5mins.toDate
```

Answer (score 1):

JODA is definitely the preferred way to handle timestamps in scala/java, if you don't mind adding the library.

```
import org.joda.time
DateTime.now.plusMinutes(5)
```

And if you want to get back to a java Date

```
DateTime.now.plusMinutes(5).toDate()
```